# Rails 4 - find nested attributes, select certain child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have and object with a nested model. I am currently getting all the nested objects like so:

```
@no = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]).children
```

Now, one of these children has an attribute that identifies them as the favorite. How can I get the favorite child from among the children?

In addition, how can I edit the attributes using `fields_for` for just that single object in the view/update?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer like you seem to do every time you ask a question on StackOverflow...

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank you for your answer and comment. Your answer helped me in the first part of my question. I will certainly accept a solution when all parts of my question are answered. For example, this question is still partly unanswered. I still need to know how to update attributes for the child object.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code for the second question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the name of your attribute that identifies the record as the favorite, but let's say it is a `boolean` named `is_favorite`. Considering this abose, the following should work:

```
children = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]).children
@favorited_children = children.where(is_favorite: true) # return 0..N records! not only 0..1 !
```

To edit its attributes, you can do as following (you will have to translate it in ERB or HAML, depending on what your app uses):

```
form_for @favorited_children do |form_builder|
  form_builder.text_field :name
  form_builder.check_box :is_favorite
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at using an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

This basically works by creating instance methods you can chain onto the child association, like so:

```
#app/models/parent.rb
Class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children do
       def favorites
           where(is_favorite: true) #-> to use MrYoshi's example
       end
    end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
@parent = Parent.find params[:id]
@favorites = @parent.children.favorites
```